# rsync include specific files and exclude directory

Tags: rsync

I have a directory structure as below:

```
base
├── config.yml
├── build
│   └── output.yml
│   └── <multiple level sub-directories each having many files including *.c and *.h files>
├── <source directories - having many sub-directories with various files including *.c and *.h files>
│   ├── <xyz>
|   │   ├── <x1>
|   │   .
│   |   └── <xy>
│   .
│   .
│   └── <abc>
├── <more directories, each having multiple files including *.c and *.h files>
```

I need to sync this directory to remote, but I only need *.c and *.h files. Also complete 'build' directory needs to be excluded. I am running below command:

`rsync -avm --include '*/' --include='*.c' --include='*.h' --exclude='*' base "$target_loc"`

This is syncing all *.c and *.h files which is desired but it also syncs *.c and *.h files from build and its sub directories

I tried
`rsync -avm --include '*/' --include='*.c' --include='*.h' --exclude='build' --exclude='*' base "$target_loc"`. It still syncs files from build and it's sub directories.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I think you need to put `--exclude='build'` before `--include '*/'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put `--exclude='build'` before `--include '*/'`. Both of these rules could apply to the "build" directory, and whichever is given first takes precedence, so to get the `--exclude` rule to override the `--include` rule, you need to list it first.

From the [`rsync` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync), in the FILTER RULES section (with my emphasis):

> As the list of files/directories to transfer is built, rsync checks
> each name to be transferred against the list of include/exclude
> patterns in turn, and **the first matching pattern is acted on**: if it is
> an exclude pattern, then that file is skipped; if it is an include
> pattern then that filename is not skipped; if no matching pattern is
> found, then the filename is not skipped.